# Wrong pagination size after filtering category product collection with custom condition

Tags: pagination, magento2

I am trying to filter the category products collection on the basis of custom product attributes, I used many ways to override the collection but every method is filtering the records per page rather than getting all the matched products before paginating.

```
We are overriding this file: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php Method we are overriding: _getProductCollection()
```

This is the code reference:

```
public function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
        }

        $jayParsedAry = [
            [
               "attribute" => "custom_attribute", 
                  [
                     [
                        "eq" => "", 
                        [
                           "null" => true 
                        ] 
                     ] 
                  ] 
               ], 
            [
               "attribute" => "custom_attribute", 
               "finset" => "1111" 
            ], 
            [
                "attribute" => "custom_attribute", 
                "finset" => "1112" 
            ] 
        ]; 
        $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter($jayParsedAry);
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

There are a total of 19 filtered records, but showing 109. On the first page, there are only 6 records showing, instead of 12 per page. Please suggest a proper way to implement filters.

[image]

I tried the above-mentioned code but didn't find any solution.